# Há algo errado com esse código?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

```
Function Check()

Dim valorA, valorB, valorG, valor2 As String
Dim rng As Range

valorG = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value
valor2 = Cells("2", ActiveCell.Column).Value

For Each rng In Range("A3:A321")

    Do While rng <> ""

        valorA = rng.Value

        valorB = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value

        If valorA = valorG Then

            If valorB = valor2 Then

                ActiveCell.Value = rng.Offset(0, 2).Value

            End If
        End If
    Loop
Next rng

End Function
```

Comment: Amigo, acredito que o código em si está ok, mas alguns comentários... um loop dentro do outro nunca é recomendado e neste caso ai sua `ActiveCell` terá sempre o último resultado desejado, quando as duas condições de seus `ifs` forem contempladas. É isso mesmo? Qual o erro? Se postar a planilha e explicar a ideia, talvez consiga uma resposta mais aproximada para auxiliar no problema.

Comment: Troque `Function Check()` por `Sub Check()`. Pois você está utilizando `ActiveCell`.

Comment: Ou se desejar criar uma Function utilize `Application.Caller` e não `ActiveCell`

Comment: Por favor, leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/75104), [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e [Seja mais específico na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104). Pois o título `Há algo errado com esse código?` não ajuda a entender o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, Vejo alguns erros:

Erro1: na declaração das variáveis valorA, valorB e valorG estão como variáveis do tipo Variant e apenas valor2 como STRING.

Se ValorA, ValorB e ValorG forem string, que tenho 99% de certeza que é o seu caso, você deve trocar a sua declaração por:

```
Dim valorA as string, valorB as string, valorG as string, valor2 As String
```

O seu código pode até funcionar com variáveis VARIANT, mas elas consomem mais memória e executam o código de forma mais lenta.

Erro2: Este procedimento deveria ser uma Sub, em vez de uma Function

Erro3: na linha "valor2 = Cells("2", ActiveCell.Column).Value", você não deveria colocar o 2 entre aspas, pois o código o interpretará como string e novamente seu código vai rodar mais lentamente.

Erro4: O seu laço condicional duplo pode ser substituido por:

```
If valorA = valorG and valorB = valor2 Then
    ActiveCell.Value = rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
End If
```

Que é uma expressão bem mais simples de se entender e de se manutenir.

Pode haver outros erros, mas precisaria saber o objetivo da macro para interpretar se é um erro. Eu particularmente não gosto de trabalhar com a propriedade offset. Prefiro fazer Cells(linha+1,coluna) ou Cells(linha,coluna+1) pois o debug fica mais fácil.